# How to transform a React Class Component with generic props to Function Component in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, typescript-typings

Writing React Component which receives generic props. In class component way, it's easy:

```
interface TableProps<D> {
  data: D
}

class Table<D> extends React.Component<TableProps<D>> { }
```

But, in function component way, I have no idea:

```
// can't figure out a way to define high order generic.
const Table2: <D extends {}> React.SFC<TableProps<D>> = ({ data }) => { }
```

How to correct it?

Comment: hmm... try: `const Table2 = <D>({ data }: TableProps<D>): React.Component<TableProps<D>> => { }`

Comment: @5ar I don't understand your code. Seems some typos here?

Answer (score 4):

You don't have to explicitly type it as `React.FC` to get a type that works as expected. (It seems fairly common to write `extends {}` but I think `extends any` communicates the actual meaning better and works just as well.)

```
const Table = <D extends any>({ data }: TableProps<D>): ReactElement => <div>{data}</div>;
```

The fact that it is compatible with `React.FC` can be seen by the following type evaluating to `true`:

```
type Dummy = typeof Table extends React.FC<any> ? true : false;
```

Comment: Omitting `React.FC` is a good solution as well especially for generic functions

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you can't declare a constant of a type and leave a free generic parameter (such a `D`). You can do it with a function type, but not with an interface/class type. A workaround would be to create a function that returns the component function:

```
interface TableProps<D> {
  data: D
}
let Table2: <D>()=>React.SFC<TableProps<D>> = function<D>(){
  return ({data}) => {
    return <div></div>;
  }
}
//Usage
let Table2ForNumbers = Table2<number>();
let d = <Table2ForNumbers data={0}></Table2ForNumbers>;
```

**Note** This solution allows you to use `Table2` as a factory for typed function components, so you can have type safe instantiations of `Table2` for specific types, such as `number` in the example above.

Comment: Your solution works but brings a little inconvenience in using it. And it's unfriendly for ppl use vanilla javascript.

Comment: Not untrue, the is an extra function there only for the benefit of the TS compiler. You can use any insantiation of Table2 in JS though (you can use `Table2ForNumbers` for any type as JS does not care, you might have `Table2ForAny` for JS consumers)

Comment: it's sad that JSer can't use Table2 as component directly. They have to either instantiate a component first or import an instantiated component. The usage divergence between TSer and JSer may force maintainers writing two documents about its usage, and cause ppl hard to drop TS type.

Comment: @5ar has a solution in the comments that looks to work the same way for TS/JS but the problem there is that in TS it might as well not be generic as any value for data will do

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir It's been a while but either I'm missing something here or the TS compiler has seen improvements or something? Because I just tried out 5ar's suggestion and while it needed some adjustments (see my answer), the restriction through the generic type works just fine.

Comment: @AndyO there is a preference to type functions as `React.FC` to endure the function is properly typed. This adds `children` to the prop and also add other properties to the function itself. You can skip the annotation altogether, you are right. I was reading it more in the context of: I want to use this annotation, how can I make the function generic.

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir Ah, I see. I actually do prefer using `React.FC` but just for readability's sake and in case the API changes. Optional children even seems like a disadvantage to me - too ambiguous, since most components either require children or don't. And it's been a long time since I've used propTypes and defaultProps (prefer destructuring with default values). Which is why I don't hesitate much about not using it in cases like this one.

Answer (score 0):

pretty sure what you're after is something like this since i'm fairly sure SFC just render out to a function that returns JSX can just rewrite that too....

```
const foo = (props: IGenericProps<number>) => {
    return (
        <div>

        </div>
    )
}
```